# Node-Red Behind Reverse Proxy with CSRF enabled - Unable to Deploy/Login

Tags: node-red

NodeRed 0.17.5

I am placing Node-Red server behind a reverse-proxy (Nginx). Accessing it via `http://:1880` is fine. But the moment I click on deploy/login, I am getting this error:

> ForbiddenError: invalid csrf token

I believe the Node-Red server does not include CSRF token in its POST page. Is this a known issue?

By the way, it is necessary to use CSRF as I am alternating a node.js reverse proxy engine that relies heavily on CSRF token so disabling it is not an option Also, the client is on the public Internet.

Comment: Since this is already being discussed in an open issue do you want to remove this question?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [issue](https://github.com/node-red/node-red/issues/1542) you raised there is no CSRF support currently in Node-RED

Answer (score 0):

Node-RED uses Express behind the covers, so implementing this:

https://github.com/expressjs/csurf

should be trivial.  The way to go about it is to configure your settings.js file:

https://nodered.org/docs/configuration

Inject the correct middleware into the httpNodeMiddleware setting to get Node-RED to return the token.